# Clone hdd with a few bad sectors

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, bad-sectors

I want to clone my hdd before it dies. I have narrowed down the bad sectors to a very small area. It is small but has caused a lot of problems from time to time. When I try to clone, it gets hung up because of this and will fail. Chkdsk did not fix it and it hangs when analyzing for a defrag. I also used Victoria to try and repair/remap the bad sectors but it has been unsuccessful. I just want to clone the drive, not save it, so I am no longer concerned with the drives health. How can I partition off 200-300 sectors? I have found no other options.

Answer (score 1):

You might also have posted at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ It’s a toss-up, depending on whether it can be done with the software that comes with your operating system or not.

I am going to assume (and, please correct me if I am wrong), than you don’t technically want to “clone” your hard drive, just to get all of the data off it before it dies (which would still be better than nothing, even if you ***do*** want to clone).

In which case, you simply cannot beat [Unstoppable Copier](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/unstoppable-copier.htm-0)  which helped me in similar situations, and also with damaged optical media.

It is free of costs & runs on both Widows and Linux.  The review which I linked says

> Good transfer speeds | Recovery of damaged files | Can rebuild files even if not completely copied from source
>
> Unstoppable Copier wins hands down in the reliability category. Not only does it transfer faster than the normal Windows copier, it is also able to recover partial files from damaged media or corrupt areas of a hard disk drive.
>
> This program is not a miracle worker but I gave it several scratched DVDs that were denied by my Windows copier and it was able to get me a complete backup of the files on the disk. I am very impressed by the software and its uses.
>
> I do not believe it is the intention of the project to do so, but I think this could be an even better program if it was able to be used in place of the Windows copier. It is portable and installable but both versions must be launched in order to do file transfers.
>
> The output of the program is outstanding and gives you a very good idea of which files have copied successfully and which files will be re-attempted. With its unique ability to recover damaged files, this copying program is the most reliable of the programs I tested.